# Unable to programatically render out ajax calendar extender in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, calendar

I need to programmatically render out ajax calendar extender but I was not able to get the params of **EditableField** and new **EventHandler(HandleTextboxTextChanged)** correctly.

I learn this method of render of ajax calendar picker from this link: 
[Dynamically add CalendarExtender to Textbox subclass server control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83770/dynamically-add-calendarextender-to-textbox-subclass-server-control)

Here are my codes inside Page_load:

```
        TextBox tbDOB = new TextBox();
        tbDOB.ID = this.ID + "tbDOB";
        tbDOB.Text = this.EditableField.TextValue;
        tbDOB.TextChanged += new EventHandler(HandleTextboxTextChanged);

        CalendarExtender calExender = new CalendarExtender();
        calExender.PopupButtonID = "Image1";
        calExender.TargetControlID = tbDOB.ID;
        phTravellerForm.Controls.Add(calExender);
```

Thank you in advance.